# Passing an array of objects to Attribute constructor

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I have custom attribute that takes array of objects. I am trying to pass an array of objects to it, but receive compiler error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

Here is the code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(Person[] people)
    {
         People = people;
    }

    public Person[] People{get; private set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

I saw some articles online, but haven't seen any closer to mine. Am I doing something wrong or it is bug? If it is not bug can someone explain why I can't pass array of `Person`? I tried array of string and it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because an array of `string` is a compile-time constant whereas an array of `Person` is not. This isn't a bug, it's a limitation. The best way around it, that I've found, is by using reflection to set the attributes properties on creation of the object - but it's not pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining. Do you know why it is limited? What is wrong passing array of objects?

Comment: @Dilshod, attributes are applied to the `Type`, not the object. This means that there's no real way for the CLR to apply them to individual objects.

Comment: @Dilshod, in your case the best approach would be to pass an array of strings to the attribute and then load those `Person` objects at run-time.

Comment: @Dilshod, here is some more [reading by Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876208/if-attributes-are-only-constructed-when-they-are-reflected-into-why-are-attribu).

Comment: in my real app I have two parameters, one is array of strings and second parameter is array of MyClass. I need to pass List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>. I could pass array of strings, but is it efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @Dilshod, you can probably pass that key value pair (though I don't **know** that it will compile). If you can pass the KVP then do so, it's a more accurate representation of the data model.

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> didn't work too. not sure which way will be very efficient.

Comment: @Dilshod you'll probably need to stick with string arrays then and just use indexes to initialize what you need.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is no more options. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error quoted comes when you try to ***apply*** your attribute to some code element. As in:

```
[My(new[] { new Person(), })]
```

You cannot use an array like that. While the expression in `()` *is* an array creation expression, it is not an array creation expression of an attribute parameter type since, by definition, the class `Person` is not an attribute parameter type.